# Add value to registry

Tags: registry

I'm creating a batch file to configure an application we use on our network that uses user specific registry settings so that all users have the same settings even if a new user logs on. I have exported the relevant registry values and need to add them to a batch file so they can be transferred to other machines. I have added all of them except one. The key I'm having a problem with is...

```
@=hex:48,4c,ce,01,00,00,0c,26
```

How do I add this to the registry with a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
reg add HKLM\Software\.. /t REG_DWORD /v @=hex:48,4c,ce,01,00,00,0c,26 /d 0
```

Save as ".bat" and not like a "Name.bat.txt"